# Compatibility Spring Boot 3.x and Spring Boot 2.7.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are two applications, first application work on Spring Boot 3.x, second application work on Spring Boot 2.7.x, from the second apllication pull dependensys which contains `Entity` at run Spring Boot 3.x application i get eror `Not a managed type`, firs case use `javax`, second case use `jakarta`.
Is it possible to Spring Boot 3.x use `Entity` which use Spring Boot 2.7.x?

Comment: No it isn't. 2.7 is JavaEE, 3.0 is JakartaEE and those aren't compatible.

Comment: This is exactly one of the big (if not biggest) breaking changes when going from 2.7 to 3.0. Spring Boot 2.7 uses JakartaEE 8 / Java EE 8, while 3.0 uses JakartaEE 9. and the big breaking change with JakartaEE 9 is moving a lot of libraries from the `javax.*` namespace to `jakarta.*` namespace.

Comment: @Saintka did you try first reading the release notes of Spring Boot 3.0 and the migration guide? You are expected to investigate before trying to open a question here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (topic Search, and research).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **NO**. it is not going to work and both of your projects must be either on version 2 or 3. The reason behind that is as following:

**Spring Framework and related libraries**: Spring Boot 3 uses Spring Framework 6.0, introducing potential compatibility breaks with libraries designed for older versions. This could lead to runtime errors or unexpected behavior.

**Hibernate**: Though the core JPA APIs remained mostly unchanged, Spring Boot 3 updates its internal Hibernate configuration and dependencies. You might encounter issues if the library application relies on specific Hibernate features or versions incompatible with Spring Boot 3's defaults.

If possible, prioritize updating the library application to a version compatible with Spring Boot 3. This helps eliminate most compatibility concerns and provides access to the latest features and bug fixes.